# Passing values to DataTemplates with attached properties

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm utilizing a data grid which has three columns of type `DataGridTemplateColumn`. These columns share almost identical behaviors and, as a consequence, utilize almost identical templates. The templates are copy-paste with a few resources changed out.

I would like to refactor the templates in to a generic version which uses an attached property to provide the necessary data. I've tried this but have been unable to access the property from inside the `CellTemplate.`

Methods I've tried are:

- Bindings using RelativeSource: TemplatedParent.
- Bindings using RelativeSource with various AncestorTypes.
- Adding `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits` to the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` of the attached property.

The CellTemplate seems to have an odd degree of separation from its surroundings. What am I missing. If nothing, what is the appropriate solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you show a code where you are trying to achieve this?

Comment: Please paste the code or share your solution you came up with, I think I am seeing the same problem here.  I cannot attach behaviors to hierarchical datatemplates

Answer (score 0):

A code example from you would have been helpful, but assuming that you have attached your property to the `DataGrid`, you should be able to bind to it from the `CellTemplate` using the following (untested):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(YourNamespace:YourClassName.YourAttachedPropertyName),
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, FallbackValue=''}" />
```

If you attached the property to the `DataGridTemplateColumn`, you would use:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(YourNamespace:YourClassName.YourAttachedPropertyName),
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridTemplateColumn}, FallbackValue=''}" />
```

The `FallbackValue` property is not required, but it's a good practice to use it to avoid binding errors if the binding source can't be found.

Comment: without trying it out, i think this will not work because the grid rows are not part of the visual tree, thus cannot access datagridtemplatecolumn as anchestorType. at leat this happens to GridViewColumns in a ListView